# MySQL Stored Procedure Host IP security

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, ip, host

I have recently taken up a role as a **MySQL** DBA, having spent many years as a **MS-SQL DBA**. And I'm trying to get my head around a few differences.

I have some stored procedures that need amending, which in itself is perfectly straightforward. But have a question about the reasoning behind specifying the specific IP in the definer.

I have a stored procedure where the **Create** line is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`sky`@`192.168.32.28` PROCEDURE `SP1`.........
```

My company has a web application running on 4 front ends, load balanced boxes. When necessary the users will run the report, which calls a simple stored proc called `'SP1'` (name changed for convenience). The IP address is for first front end box, and the others end in **29-31**.

My question is if the server (192.168.32.28) goes down for whatever reason, will this stored procedure be able to run? By specifying this precise IP address rather than a range, does it stop the other front end boxes from running the procedure? Why would you want to specify a single IP?

I apologize if these are stupid questions, but I cannot find an answer to this anywhere.

This is my first ever posting, ever. As in all my years, I have been able to find what I need from forums like this. I expect I am just not using the right search criteria, as I cannot be the first to ask this.
Thanks.

Comment: I am not a DBA but still ... I don't think `host_name` has any signification on calling system's _up and running_ status. The reference documentation does not talk about it but valid user accounts that does exist for the sp to be executed. please read [Create Procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) and [Access Control for Stored Programs and Views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-security.html)

Comment: Thanks for you response, but I have already read all the manuals about access control and security invoking. But it does not answer my question. Each of the manuals only refer to 'localhost' and nothing about why/what happens if using a specific IP.